# Firebase Code Running After Everything Else

Tags: android, firebase, listener, onstart

I'm making an Android app with Firebase and within one of my activities I need to read data from Firebase **before** doing anything else. To do so, I'm using a `ValueEventListener`. The problem is, Android is running the rest of the code **first** and then it gets the result/runs the code within the listener's `onDataChange()` method. I know this because I debugged using Logs and indeed the result arrives a couple of seconds after the rest of the code runs.

I've seen examples of people writing the code you want to run after the query within another method, and then calling that method inside the `onDataChange()`. I tried doing that, also tried moving the listener to another class and calling the method and even tried controlling the flow of the code with variables, nothing worked. Any ideas of what can I do?

Btw, I don't know if this affects in any way of not but, my piece of code that depends on Firebase's result is inside the `onStart()` method, so I suppose Android would always run the `onStart()` first and then get the result from the listener.

Thanks!

Comment: You could move all your code into a method and call it in the onStart()

Comment: Check **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847694/how-to-return-datasnapshot-value-as-a-result-of-a-method/47853774)** out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ValueEventListeners are asynchronous, so they won't run first. Instead, try calling a function that does what you wanted to do with the listener from inside the `onDataChange()` function.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. However in this case calling another function doesn't work since Android still runs onStart() first and then runs the code inside onDataChange(). I made it work by having another activity receive the data first and then send it.